# Diagonalization calculator of definite quadratic forms using the "completing the square" method

Tags: algorithms, positive-definite, quadratic-programming, calculator, completing-the-square

In this question: [Calculating the maximum value of a quadratic polynomial on several variables with some restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531195/calculating-the-maximum-value-of-a-quadratic-polynomial-on-several-variables-wit), I asked about finding the maximum value of a certain quadratic polynomial with some restrictions on the variables. Actually, the function was $$f(x_1,\dots,x_7)=-x_1^2-2x_2^2-5x_3^2-4x_4^2-2x_5^2-71x_6^2-2x_7^2+2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+2x_1x_4+2x_1x_6+2x_4x_5+2x_6x_7, $$
which is a negative definite quadratic form, i.e. $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)<0$ for all nonzero $(x_1,\dots,x_7)\in \Bbb R^7$. The answers used the "completing the square method" to express $f$ as sums of negative squares: $$\begin{aligned}f(x) = -(x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_6)^2&\\ 
-(x_2-x_3-x_4-x_6)^2&\\ 
- 3(x_3-\frac23x_4-\frac23x_6)^2&\\ 
- \frac23(x_4-\frac32x_5-5x_6)^2&\\ 
- \frac12 (x_5-10x_6)^2&\\ 
- (x_6-x_7)^2 &\\
- x_7^2&
\end{aligned}$$

Now let $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a negative definite quadratic form on $n$ variables. Is there a calculator or program that expresses $f$ as sums of negative sqaures as in the above situation?

Clearly we have an algorithm for doing this: we first gather the terms containing $x_1$, and get $$f=-c(x_1-f_1(x_2,\dots,x_n))^2 + g_1(x_2,\dots,x_n),$$
and so on. I can do this by hand if $n$ is not large, but if $n$ gets large, then it takes too much time for doing this. For example, if $$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=-x_1^2-3x_2^2-5x_3^2-7x_4^2-4x_5^2-2(x_6^2+\cdots+x_{15}^2)+2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+2x_1x_4+2x_1x_5+2(x_5x_6+x_6x_7+\cdots+x_{14}x_{15}),$$
then this is a negative definite quadratic form but the calculation becomes too complicated to do it by hand. So I am finding a calculating program for doing this.

Comment: taking the negative of your form, I  got it (second answer)  as the sum of the squares of these rows,   $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new matrix is symmetric unimodular.  Meanwhile, here is a rational version that requires a diagonal rational matrix in the middle.

In dimension $8$ or larger, a symmetric positive definite integer matrix of determinant $1$  is not guaranteed to be expressible as $P^T P...$
My try to write it my $H$  ( the negative of your matrix) as some $ H=P^T P$  seemed to fail. One simple way to confirm:  write a computer program, integer variables $x_1$ up to $x_{15} $ as vector $v,$  in a multiple loop, and count the number of ways that $v^T  H v = 1$  which would be the count of your $f(v) = -1.$ The count of $v$   with $v \cdot v = 1$  is exactly $30,$  those being $\pm e_i$ where $e_i$   has a one in position $i$  with the other spots $0.$  If the count of $f(v) = -1$  is different from $30$  the failure is confirmed.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$
Q^T =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  &  -  \frac{ 15 }{ 34 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 34 }{ 31 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 31 }{ 28 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 28 }{ 25 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 22 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 22 }{ 19 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 19 }{ 16 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 13 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 10 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
D = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 34 }{ 7 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 31 }{ 34 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 28 }{ 31 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 25 }{ 28 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 22 }{ 25 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 22 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 19 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 13 }{ 16 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 10 }{ 13 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 10 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 7 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$ 
Q =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 15 }{ 34 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 34 }{ 31 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 31 }{ 28 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 28 }{ 25 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 22 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 22 }{ 19 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 19 }{ 16 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 13 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 10 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$ 
H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to compute the number of vectors with$v^T Hv=1$?

Comment: @user302934   computer program, multiple loop, one for each variable.

Comment: One more question please: Suppose we have a symmetric unimodular matrix $Q$ that is diagonalizable, so that we know that there is a matrix $A$ so that $Q=AA^T$. In this case is there a computer program / algorithm for finding such $A$?